# Using strtok to split the string

Tags: c++, arrays

```
 char *strings[30];
 char Policystr[4096] = "the|string|to|split"; 
 char delims[] = "|";
 int i = 0;

 strings[i] = strtok( Policystr, delims )
 while( strings[i] != NULL  ) 
{
        MessageBoxA(NULL,strings[i],"stringsComparison",MB_OK);
        strings[++i] = strtok( NULL, delims );          
}
for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
 {
     MessageBoxA(NULL,strings[j],"strings",MB_OK);
 }
```

i am new to C++ i get all strings in first loop if i am able to print the same in second loop i don't know y i am not getting

thanks in advance

Comment: `MessageBoxA(NULL,strings[j],"stringsComparison",MB_OK);` That can't be right. `j` never changes in the top loop and, in fact, doesn't even exist there.

Comment: Try changing `strings[j]` to `strings[i]` in the first loop...

Comment: If you're using C++, see if you can use `std::string` and `std::vector`. Splitting a `std::string` is trivial, especially considering `boost` probably has something exactly for this purpose, but even without `boost` it should be easy.

Comment: strtok() is the source of all evil ... If you REALLY want to avoid boost, at least use strtok_s().

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth ...or `strtok_r` for POSIX.

Comment: _DO NOT USE PLAIN CHAR ARRAYS_

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *strings[30];
    char Policystr[4096] = "the|string|to|split"; 
    char delims[] = "|";

    int i = 0;
    strings[i] = strtok( Policystr, delims );
    while( strings[i] != NULL  ) 
    {
        printf("%d '%s'\n", i, strings[i]);
        strings[++i] = strtok( NULL, delims );          
    }

    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
    {
        printf("%d '%s'\n", j, strings[j]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 'the'
1 'string'
2 'to'
3 'split'
0 'the'
1 'string'
2 'to'
3 'split'
```

Comment: This question is for C++, though.

Comment: The program above is C++. (Though I believe it's also legal C.)

Comment: Though a C++ pedant (...) might argue you shall `#include <cstdio>` etc, `std::cout`, write `int main()`, use `std::string`.

Comment: Those are certainly other ways I could have written the program.

Comment: Just by reading your code I thought you might have misread that this is a C++ question; my fail.

Comment: What does the while loop do? Particularly what is, "strings[++i] = strtok( NULL, delims );" doing?

Comment: The `while` loop tokenizes the string until `strtok` returns `NULL` indicating no more tokens. When you pass a `NULL` as the first parameter to `strtok`, it returns the next token.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged C++ but you are manipulating string data like a C programmer from 1985 (no offence, it's just that the use of `strtok` is generally discouraged nowadays). Since you're using C++, I would recommend avoiding C library functions and instead using functionality available in the C++ Standard Library. Here is a fully self-contained working example of one way to split a `std::string` in C++. I'm quite a novice at C++ so this may not be the most efficient way. The benefits to this approach are:

1. Memory management is handled automatically, with no arbitrary limits imposed by your program on the size of input or output.
2. No use of old (and discouraged) C library function.
3. You don't have to modify the original input data to split the string, meaning you can operate on const-qualified input. This is something that `strtok` is unable to do, because `strtok` modifies the original input.
4. You can still use this method if you have a `char *` or `char []` buffer, because you can turn it into an `std::string` (if it is not terminated by a null character you will also need to give the constructor the length of the buffer).
5. If you want to create a message box from one of the `std::string` objects in the vector, you can use the `.c_str()` member function, e.g.

   ```
   MessageBoxA(NULL, results[i].c_str(), "strings", MB_OK);
   ```

---

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::string delims = "|";
    std::string policyStr = "the|string|to|split";
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    size_t lastOffset = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        size_t offset = policyStr.find_first_of(delims, lastOffset);
        results.push_back(policyStr.substr(lastOffset, offset - lastOffset));
        if (offset == std::string::npos)
            break;
        else
            lastOffset = offset + 1; // add one to skip the delimiter
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        std::cout << results[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initlaize `i=0` before starting using it. In the first loop you have to write `MessageBoxA(NULL,strings[i],"stringsComparison",MB_OK);`